# bash: debug (xtrace) target of redirections

Tags: bash, shell-script, io-redirection

Is there a way to show redirections with `bash -x`?

```
$ bash -exc 'for word in foo bat baz; do echo $word >$word; done'
+ for word in foo bat baz
+ echo foo
+ for word in foo bat baz
+ echo bat
+ for word in foo bat baz
+ echo baz
```

I would like output like this so the script can be executed with `#!/usr/bin/env -S bash -ex` and would describe the steps it takes:

```
$ bash -exc 'for word in foo bat baz; do echo $word >$word; done'
+ for word in foo bat baz
+ echo foo >foo
+ for word in foo bat baz
+ echo bat >bat
+ for word in foo bat baz
+ echo baz >baz
```

I tried searching the internet, but the keywords bash, debug and redirection lead to questions about how to redirect debug logs, but not how to log/debug redirections.

Comment: Interesting... Can you give as a bit more detail on how you will use this? If we understand what your final objective is, we might be able to give better answers. Are you looking for `strace` perhaps?

Comment: I like to know what my ">$word" expanded to, w/o adding an extra echo statement.

Comment: `strace -e openat` is interesting but includes much stuff i am not interested in. Actually I am not trying to debug the script but would like for it describe the steps while doing them. it generates some files via `cat >file <EOT ...` which are only displayed as `+ cat`, i would like to get `+ cat >file`, I'll see if i can expand the question in that regard.